# Mate panel not working with Compiz in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, compiz, mate

So, I tried to set up Compiz as my window manager in Mate. I am running Ubuntu 16.04, but I didn't install Ubuntu Mate. Instead, I installed a different flavor of Ubuntu and installed Mate in it. When I login I can't move Windows around and the panel for Mate is completely unresponsive. I can do Ctrl+Alt+T to open a terminal and such, but I want to be able to use Compiz in Mate so I can use features like the Compiz Cube. I believe I used [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/11/how-to-use-compiz-in-ubuntu-mate-1404.html) guide to get Compiz to work, except I had no need for installing Compiz because it is already installed and used as default in the official Ubuntu flavor.

Comment: It may help if you be specific about "I installed a different flavor of Ubuntu". Which flavor is that?

Comment: @DKBose The Offical one (Unity)

Comment: I have installed MATE DE with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop`. I think you should use `mate-tweak` to change window manager (go to _Windows_, _Window manager_ and select  _Compiz_ here).